# Accordion in Sencha touch

Tags: javascript, ipad, safari, accordion, sencha-touch

Is there any example with code for Accordion like effect in Sencha touch. I need to implement the same for the iPad .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure why this got downvoted but there absolutely is courtesy of a plugin by Mitchell Simoens:

https://github.com/mitchellsimoens/Ext.layout.AccordionLayout

Comment: Thx a lot for understanding the question clearly and also for the upvote. While the plugin u provided as ref comes very close, the only thing while testing on the iPad was that it does not seem to show the transition smoothly..Not sure if that can be configured as a setting OR if it is bcoz of the iPad..So is this the only available plugin as of now..thx again..

Comment: As far as I know yes it is the only one currently. But since it's open source you're at liberty to fix it and submit a pull request if you find a way to fix it in the plugin's code. I feel like I'm talking for the developer, sorry.

Comment: it  has a problem.. when i am adding an item having subitems its not rendering at all... how can i fix this..?

Comment: You cant its one of the limitations. It can render HTML code fine though, so if you don't use components you should be ok.